# sortByKey() function in Spark Scala not working properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run a `sortByKey()` function on the following text file.

```
EMP_NAME EMP_ID SALARY
Adam     22      100
Bob      25      102
Bob      28      104
Chris    29      110
```

I am taking `EMP_NAME` as the key for the following text file. I am running the following command: `textFile.sortByKey()`
I am getting the following output:

```
Bob
Bob
Adam
Chris
```

Help is appreciated..Thank You.

Comment: Please, add your code so it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using SparkConffiguration as

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
```

Then the number of partition created by default is 1.

But  if you are using

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
```

and you have got extra cores available for Spark it will partition the data based upon it for parallel execution of task Spark can do.

To get the number of partition Spark has made :

```
println(partitions.length)
//For my machine it was 2
```

If the data is partitioned then the sorting is done on the elements in *that partition only* and at end output from each partition is merged.To avoid this scenario you can enforce the numPartition as 1 in sortByKey method and get the data into one partition and then sort it.

```
textFile.sortByKey(numPartitions = 1).foreach(println)
```

Which will make it partition into 1 and you will be getting proper sorted output across the input data.

Comment: To get the number of partitions on a RDD call `getNumPartitions()`

Comment: If we force it to use 1 partition, doesn't that limit the distribution capabilities?? isn't there a more foolproof way to distribute AND have a guaranteed sorted result?

Comment: @Aetos Use DF and sort by that column.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm providing the dataset and the code to perform the functionality of sorting by key, if you won't found it helpful then please provide us the code, we will look into the issue.

Data ->
(tab seperated file)

```
EMP_NAME    EMP_ID  SALARY
Adam    22  100
Bob 25  102
Bob 28  104
Chris   29  110
```

Code ->

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

/*
* @author Kshitij Kulshrestha
*/

object A1 {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

// set up environment
val sparkHome = "/usr/spark_pack/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.4/";
val sparkMasterUrl = "spark://SYSTEMX:7077";

val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("A1")
.setMaster("local[2]")
.setSparkHome(sparkHome)

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val dataRDD = sc.textFile("src/Source/A1_data").filter { !_.contains("EMP_NAME") }
.map { x =>
{
val temp = x.split("\t")

((temp(0)), (temp(1), temp(2)))
}
}

val sortedDataRDD = dataRDD coalesce(1) sortByKey()
sortedDataRDD foreach (println(_))

}
}
```

Output ->

```
(Adam,(22,100))
(Bob,(25,102))
(Bob,(28,104))
(Chris,(29,110))
```

Comment: This code will not work in Cluster nor when it is made as local[*] as number of partitions will not remain 1.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
 sc.parallelize([['Chris',29,110],['Bob',28,104],['Bob',25,102],['Adam',22,100]]).groupBy(lambda x: x[0]).sortByKey().flatMap(lambda x: list(x[1])).collect()
```

> [['Adam', 22, 100], ['Bob', 25, 102], ['Bob', 28, 104], ['Chris', 29, 110]]

Scala:

```
sc.parallelize(List(Array("Chris",29,110),Array("Bob",28,104),Array("Bob",25,102),Array("Adam",22,100))).groupBy(x => x(0).asInstanceOf[String]).sortByKey().flatMap(x=> x._2).collect()
```

> Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(Adam, 22, 100), Array(Bob, 28, 104), Array(Bob, 25, 102), Array(Chris, 29, 110))

You may want to put the other columns as part of your key if you want to include them in your sorting criteria. So in the example above sorting of Bob by the 2nd column won't be there.